# Fixed size set to contain the maximum number of given sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have about 1000 sets of size <=5 containing numbers 1 to 100.

```
{1}, {4}, {1,3}, {3,5,6}, {4,5,6,7}, {5,25,42,67,100} ...
```

Is it possible to find a set of size 20 that contains the maximum number of given sets?

Checking each of `100!/(80!*20!)` sets, is inefficient.

Comment: Could you mean the [Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) or is it just me misunderstanding your wording?

Comment: @ThreeFx Even I strongly feel that the problem is under the realm of NP complete problems, but it is not exactly the same as the well-known Set cover problem.

Comment: In set cover we want the minimum number of sets whose union has 100 elements. I want the maximum number of sets whose union has 20 elements.

Comment: You can probably save a bit of time by finding sets that are subsets of other sets first, which would also allow you to determine which sets are partial subsets of others. Linking the partial sets could then be used to determine which sets to union. Although, that'll almost certain result in a heuristic solution, but I don't think it can be avoided as checking each of the sets actually seems like the most efficient way to go, but you can do better with backtracking and build only a fraction of them.

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32155/755

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure this is NP complete.

Consider the related problem where we get a reward of x for each set, but have to pay a price of y for each number that we want to allow.  (A set only pays the reward if all the numbers it contains have been paid for.)

You can solve this type of problem using the [max flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) by:

1. Setting up a source node
2. Setting up a destination node
3. Setting up a node for each set
4. Setting up a node for each number
5. Add edge from source to each set with capacity x
6. Add edge from each number to dest with capacity y
7. For each number a in set s, add edge from s to a with infinite capacity

Solving the maximum flow problem on this graph (from the source to destination node) finds a minimum cut cost c.

The net amount of money we would make would be N.x-c (where N is the number of sets).

If we can choose y (e.g. by bisection) such that we have selected exactly 20 numbers, then we have managed to solve for the maximum number of sets with 20 numbers.

Comment: Thank You. I will check max flow and I'll accept the answer.