# Need an algorithm approach to calculate meal plan

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations

I’m having trouble solving a deceptively simple problem.  My girlfriend and I are trying to formulate weekly meal plans and I had this brilliant idea that I could optimize what we buy in order to maximize the things that we could make from it.  The trouble is, the problem is not as easy as it appears.  Here’s the problem statement in a nutshell:

The problem:
Given a list of 100 ingredients and a list of 50 dishes that are composed of one or more of the 100 ingredients, find a list of 32 ingredients that can produce the maximum number of dishes.

This problem seems simple, but I’m finding that computing the answer is not trivial.  The approach that I’ve taken is that I’ve computed a combination of the 32 ingredients as a 100 bit string with 32 of the bits set.  Then I do a check of what dishes can be made with that ingredient number.  If the number of dishes is greater than the current maximum, I save off the list.  Then I compute the next valid ingredient combination and repeat, repeat, and repeat.

The number of combinations of the 32 ingredients is staggering!  The way that I see it, it would take about 300 trillion years to calculate using my method.  I’ve optimized the code so that each combination takes a mere 75 microseconds to figure out.  Assuming that I can optimize the code, I might be able to reduce the run time to a mere trillion years.

I’m thinking that a completely new approach is in order.  I'm currently coding this in XOJO (REALbasic), but I think the real problem is with approach rather than specific implementation.  Anybody have an idea for an approach that has a chance of completion during this century?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvellous algorithm for computing this in O(1) using BASIC, which this comment is too narrow to contain.

Comment: Perhaps similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104859/fixed-size-set-to-contain-the-maximum-number-of-given-sets)?

Comment: Matt, I'd be interested to see what you have.  Can you PM me something to look at?

Comment: Peter, yes, that is essentially the same problem.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.  I'll study it a bit to see if I can get somewhere with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mcdowella's branch and bound solution will be a big improvement over exhaustive enumeration, but it might still take a few thousand years.  This is the kind of problem that is really best solved by an [ILP solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Assuming that the set of ingredients for meal i is given by R[i] = { R[i][1], R[i][2], ..., R[i][|R[i]|] }, you can encode the problem as follows:

- Create an integer variable x[i] for each ingredient 1 <= i <= 100.  Each of these variables should be constrained to the range [0, 1].
- Create an integer variable y[i] for each meal 1 <= i <= 50.  Each of these variables should be constrained to the range [0, 1].
- For each meal i, create |R[i]| additional constraints of the form y[i] <= x[R[i][j]] for 1 <= j <= |R[i]|.  These will guarantee that we can only set y[i] to 1 if all of meal i's ingredients have been included.
- Add a constraint that the sum of all x[i] must be <= 32.
- Finally, the objective function should be the sum of all y[i], and we should be trying to maximise this.

Solving this will produce assignments for all the variables x[i]: 1 means the ingredient should be included, 0 means it should not.

My feeling is that a commercial ILP solver like CPLEX or Gurobi will probably solve a 150-variable ILP problem like this in milliseconds; even freely available solvers like [lp_solve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/), which as a rule are *much* slower, should have no problems.  In the unlikely case that it seems to be taking forever, you can still solve the LP relaxation, which will be very fast (milliseconds) and will give you (a) an upper bound on the maximum number of meals that can be prepared and (b) "hints" in the variable values: although the x[i] will in general not be exactly 0 or 1, values close to 1 are suggestive of ingredients that should be included, while values close to 0 suggest unhelpful ingredients.

Comment: I've been looking at the lp_solve documentation and have been trying to get my head around this for a few hours now.  I think that you are probably on to something but I'm new at this sort of thing and I have no idea at all about how to go about setting up an input file to run this.  I'm not even certain that lp_solve accepts matrices and determinants in the input file.  All the examples that I've seen use single integer variables.  I'll rack my brain on this for a bit more.  You've certainly given me something to think about!

Comment: Ok, I've been confused by your notation.  By |R[i]| you mean the number of elements in the R array, right?

Comment: @user3777515: Not sure why you would need to specify matrices or determinants?  All you need is the integer variables and constraints I mention.  Maybe I confused things by writing "x[i]" -- you would typically name your variables x1, x2, y1, etc.  The usual file format (MPS if I recall) is fairly simple, but once you figure it out you may find it easier to write a script to generate the ILP input file (from some higher-level description).  And yes, R[i] means the set of ingredients for meal i, and |R[i]| means the number of elements in that set.

Comment: Awesome!  I just solved it with LP_Solver in .051 seconds.  You saved me several trillion years!  Thanks!!!!

Comment: @user3777515: You're welcome, glad it turned out to be as fast as I hoped :)

Answer (score 2):

There will be a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound solution to this, but it may be too expensive to get the exact answer - ILP as suggested by j_random_hacker is probably better - the LP relaxation of that is probably a better heuristic than the relaxation proposed here, and the ILP solver will be heavily optimized.

The basic idea is that you do a recursive depth first search of a tree of partial solutions, extending them one at a time. Once you recurse far enough down to reach a fully populated solution you can start keeping track of the best solution found so far. If I label your ingredients A, B, C, D... a partial solution is a list of ingredients of length <= 32. You start with the zero-length solution, then when you visit a partial solution e.g. ABC you consider ABCD, ABCE, ... and so on, and may visit some of these.

For each partial solution you work out the maximum score that any descendant of that solution could achieve. Getting an accurate idea of this is important. Here is one suggestion - suppose you have a partial solution of length 20. This leaves 12 ingredients to be chosen, so the best you could possibly do is to make all dishes which require no more than 12 ingredients not already in the 20 you have chosen so far work out how many of those there are and this is one example of a best possible score to any descendant of the partial solution.

Now when you consider extending the partial solution ABC to ABCD or ABCE or ABCF... if you have a best solution found so far you can ignore all extensions that cannot possibly score more than the best solution so far - this means that you don't need to consider all possible combinations of your 32 ingredients.

Once you have worked out which of the possible extensions *might* contain a new best answer, your recursive search should continue with the most promising of these possible extensions, because this is the one most likely to survive finding a better best solution so far.

One way to make this fast is to code it cleverly so that recursing up and down means only small changes to the existing data structure which you typically make on the way down and reverse on the way up.

Another way is to cut corners. One obvious way is to stop when you run out of time and go for the best solution found so far at that stage. Another way is to discard partial solutions more aggressively. If you have a score so far of e.g. 100 you could discard partial solutions that couldn't score any better than 110. This speeds up the search, and you know that although you might have best a better answer than 100 whatever you missed could not have been better than 110.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I'll have to give some thought as to how that might be implemented.  Thanks for that!

Comment: The most practical approach would probably be j_random_hacker's ILP approach with an open source ILP solver. All you need to implement that is to set up the ILP problem and some glue code round the solver - probably faster too.

Answer (score 1):

Solving some discrete mathematics huh? Well [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) is the wiki.

You also have not factored in anything about quantity. For example, flour would be used in a lot of fried recipes but buying 10 pounds of flour might not be great. And cost might be prohibitive for some ingredients that your solution wants. Not to mention a lot of ingredients are in everything. (milk, water, salt, pepper, sugar things like that)

In reality, optimization to this degree is probably not necessary. But I will not provide relationship advice on SO.

As for a new solution:

I would suggest identifying a lot of what you want to make and with what, and then writing a program to suggest things to make with the rest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that wiki.  Yep, my problem is very similar.  I certainly see parallels between this problem and the knapsack and traveling salesman problems.

Your suggestion is certainly a much more solvable idea than what I'm trying to do.  If all else fails, I may fall back on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just order the list of ingredients by the number of dishes they are used in?

This would be more like a greedy solution, of course, but it should give you some clues about what ingredients are most often used. From that you can compile a list of dishes that can be cooked already with the top 30 (or whatever) ingredients. 
Also you could order the list of remaining (non-cookable) dishes by number of missing ingredients and maybe try to optimize on that to maximize the number of cookable dishes.

To be more "algorithmic", I think a **local search** is most promising here. Start with a candidate solution (random assignments to the 32 ingredients) and calculate as a fitness function the number of cookable dishes. Then check the neighboring states (switching one ingredient) and move to the state with the highest value. Repeat until a maximum is reached. Do this veeeery often and you should find a good solution. (This would be a simple greedy hill-climbing algorithm)

There are a lot of local search algorithms, you should be able to find more than enough information on the net. Most often you won't find the optimal solution (of course that depends on the problem), but a very good one nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I've already tried what you said about sorting the list by most-used ingredients.  And it does find better solutions faster, but it still takes the same amount of time to do the exhaustive search.

I've been looking into local search algorithms and you might be on to something.  I have LOTS to look into here!  Thanks!

Comment: I think exhaustive search is probably unfeasable here. Local search seems promising but its important to define a "good" neighborhood relation. If the neighborhood is too big, it still takes a very long time to calculate the next iteration. Maybe like this: start with a random assignment to the 32 ingredients and keep all non-assigned ingredients in a list ordered by "most-used". Then you could define the neighborhood as all states in which one assigned ingredient is switched with the "best" ingredient from the "unassigned" list.

Comment: That means 32 neighbor states per iteration, that should be very fast to find some local maximum. You can restart this procedure very often to find possible better solutions. You can also include random steps (choose for the switch a random ingredient from the unassigned list maybe with probability 0.5) for a change. Experiment a bit, it should be no problem since it's very fast.